# Input feature is needed to get skyline analysis in ArcGIS Pro to work

Tags: arcgis-pro, 3d, local-scene

I'm trying to recreate a skyline analysis as outlined here: [Skyline analysis: an urban environmental physical-design](https://desktop.arcgis.com/de/arcmap/latest/extensions/3d-analyst/skyline-analysis-an-urban-environmental-physical-design-aid.htm) but I'm having several difficulties.

I'm using ArcGIS Pro 3.1.0.

I work in a local scene and I created a feature class containing a projected point, which will serve as a view point. I have a scene layer containing 3D buildings of Berlin, accessed through the ArcGIS online portal, which can also be found [here on ArcGIS](https://tiles.arcgis.com/tiles/P3ePLMYs2RVChkJx/arcgis/rest/services/Buildings_Berlin/SceneServer/layers/0).

When I try to use the skyline analysis tool, I am unable to select the 3D buildings as input feature, meaning the skyline analysis will simply use a (rather flat) DEM, which doesn't help me at all.

How can I get the skyline analysis to work? It seems the layer containing the 3D buildings is not the right format but I couldn't find a fitting layer format.

Important to note: I have no previous experience with ArcGIS Pro or any other Esri product.